# Video card and PowerSupply problems, perhaps? I don't really know

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, hardware-failure

I have an Asus M4A77TD PRO MoBo, and a Gigabyte Nvidia GTS250 as video card. For several months, I have been detecting some strange things: Random hangs for a period of time in all games, for a start. When the machine is off for some time and then powered on, always produces a BSOD in the first 30 seconds of booting windows. If windows is booting this first time in safe mode, or doing a chkdsk, it also goes BSOD, no matter what. After this initial BSOD, the machine reboots, and refuses to even show POST info. I usually give it some "pumps" to the reset button, and the machine show POST info, start and boot correctly, without a problem. I can reboot it, and nothing happens, works great (except for the random freezes in games, but I don't play so much). Is only after it's being off or suspended for some hours that the problem arises. I have formatted and reinstalled this machine several times, and the problem persist. I have cheched memory with memtest86 and the windows memory tool, and it didn't detect problems with the memory.

I have tried using the debugging tools and check the minidumps to see is it's a faulty driver, but it only shows a problem with IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL related to the IRQL 2. I checked the device manager, and found a strange IRQ (-2) assigned to the PCIe controller. I entered the BIOS and deactivated everything that seemed related, even serial and parallel ports; and found certain option: `Clock for PCIe controller` with options `Enable` and `disable`. It was enabled and I disabled it. Nothings seems to have changed.

I have being told that one possible cause of the problem is that I'm using an NVidia card with ATI chipset... but that does not make sense to me. Also I've being told that it could be a problem with my Power Supply. Anyone  with a similar problem? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would absolutely suspect the power supply. Replace it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I will check and be back with results.

Comment: It was the MoBo. Faulty capacitors. Bought a new one, everything was fine. I need to change that now, because some time has passed and it's getting old. But I said  I would be back with results and forgot, sorry.